# slf4j BaseJdbcLogger not logging

Tags: logging, jdbc, slf4j, mybatis

I have added ***org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger*** logger to logback.xml to log sql and result set from jdbc.

```
<appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}] [%t] [%-5p] </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="com.business.logic" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.springframework.http.client.support" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.springframework.web.client" level="DEBUG" />

<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="asyncAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</root>
```

It seems to me that this will log sql and result set to console, but it doesn't. To deal with it, I have changed each logger's log level differently, and I figured out that it prints log only when the level of **com.business.log** is **DEBUG**

```
<logger name="com.business.logic" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.apache.ibatis.logging.jdbc.BaseJdbcLogger" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.springframework.http.client.support" level="DEBUG" />
<logger name="org.springframework.web.client" level="DEBUG" />
```

I have no idea why the level of business logic logger make influence on apache BaseJdbcLogger logger although they are set differently.

If I use mybatis-generator, which I don't, I could assume this situation. Because the mybatis access code from generator will locate on the sub package of com.business.logic, so it follows the set of com.business.logic logger. However I don't use mybatis-generator now.

Here my questions:

1. What is the reason that BaseJdbcLogger doesn't log with my current log setting?
2. If I need to change the level of **com.business.logic** to DEBUG to make BaseJdbcLogger work properly, what point of mybatis or slf4j make it?

Answer (score 0):

Since the question was posted, I cannot help thinking about it. I found one of them by myself and I will update as soon as I found the other.

Q1. What is the reason that BaseJdbcLogger doesn't log with my current log setting?

After I read an article about Mybatis logging(http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) I realised that I misunderstood the logger. 
I thought logger with **BaseJdbcLogger** would log sql and result set because it seems **BaseJdbcLogger.debug()** prints sql log !!!!

```
[2016-07-25 15:52:48] [main] [DEBUG] o.a.i.l.j.BaseJdbcLogger.debug[139] ==>  Preparing: SELECT * FROM A.
```

However I read Mybatis logging article thoroughly again and again, 
and I found that all logger examples in the article have the name with **business package** not **BaseJdbcLogger**. I still don't know the reason but I have got that I have to use logger with **business package name** not BaseJdbcLogger for sql logging.